how can I see what was deleted by sharepoint retention policy
I have a retention policy to delete after a time period.
How can I find out what was deleted and when?
Thank you

Check in the Microsoft Purview Compliance Center:
Microsoft Purview Compliance Center >> Audit Log Search >> Audit under the Solutions section
There search for Deletion Events like "FileDeleted", "ItemDeleted", or simply "Delete".  As a user it should show a "System Account" or "SharePoint App". Check also for "Retention Policy".


Do I wait to get results?

@OferGal it takes ~30 minutes for audit log to record event after event
